# Intense slideshow using z-index, php, xml, and jquery / cycle.js

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, slideshow

So I'm working on this project and the creative director has thrown a curveball my way.

He's created with flash a prototype that needs to be built with jQuery, XML (or PHP) pulling in all the content and images, and then within the same div dimensions toggle more information that's also pulled in via XML.

I'm allowed to use JS to the fullest extent which means if I'm pulling images with JS I'll give them a specific naming convention. Without further adieu:

http://joeylabs.com/sites/sgc/prototype/

Btw, for some reason this page pushes the slideshow all the way to the bottom so to view the entire thing just scroll to the bottom. :)

So what I'm ***thinking*** is:

1. Pull images from folder via php directory scan script or with jquery using an image naming convention.
2. Then using Cycle.js I'd create a variable that holds the image inside the li before with onBefore and a variable that holds the image inside the li after with onAfter, float both of them respectively in a div with a z-index 1 less than the current slide. (I don't know how to do this yet)
3. The current slide has a blinds transition and when the user clicks NEXT it is a trigger for 2 slideshows, one below and one on top .

This is all theory at this point but don't you think it would be possible to run 2 Cycle slideshows, one on top of the other with 1 trigger? Anyone have thoughts, tips, on this?

Answer (score 1):

yes, I nested each of my img in two divs and two divs to wrap things up...

```
<div id="before_window_wrapper">
  <div name="before_n_after_window">

    <div id="before_slide_wrapper">
       <div id="before_slide">
         <img src"my/image/directory/1.img"/>
       </div>
       <div id="slide_comment">
         <h3>person comment for this img goes here</h3>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="before_slide_wrapper">
      <div id="before_slide">
        <img src"my/image/directory/3.img"/>
      </div>
        <div id="slide_comment">
         <h3>person comment for this img goes here</h3>
       </div>
   </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

and:

```
<div id="after_window_wrapper">
  <div name="before_n_after_window">

    <div id="after_slide_wrapper">
       <div id="after_slide">
         <img src"my/image/directory/2.img"/>
       </div>
       <div id="slide_comment">
         <h3>person comment for this img goes here</h3>
       </div>
    </div>

    <div id="after_slide_wrapper">
      <div id="after_slide">
        <img src"my/image/directory/4.img"/>
      </div>
       <div id="slide_comment">
         <h3>person comment for this img goes here</h3>
       </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

the children of "before_n_after_window" are the divs that are being cycled:

```
$("#before_n_after_window").each(function(index){
  $(this).cycle();
});
```

The slide wrappers (before_slide_wrapper and after_slide_wrapper) are under cycle()'s complete control -fine. However, any thing nested inside of it is not, so you can place more siblings for the slides(before_slide and after_slide) - hence the "#slide_comment" div.

"before_n_after_window" is only under semi-control of cycle(), and uses your css code that doesn't conflict with its own. "#before_window_wrapper" and "#after_window_wrapper" are under your complete control(css-wise).

Now that you have"#before_n_after_window" and its children, simply iterate through them and name and point the controls for each pair:

```
var i = index;
var current_slide = $(this);

// hides the pause button
$('#pause_button_'+i).hide();
//checks index for odd or even
i = (i%=2) ? ((index+1)/2) : ((index/2)+1);

$(current_slide).cycle({
  fx:    'fade',
  pager:    '#nav_' + i,
  prev:     '#previous_button_' + i,
  next:     '#next_button_' + i,
});

// I want to only show the play or pause button at any given time
$(current_slide).cycle('pause');
$('#play_button_'+i).click(function(){
  $(current_slide).cycle('resume', true); 
  $('#pause_button_'+i).show();
  $('#play_button_'+i).hide();
});
$('#pause_button_'+i).click(function() { 
  $(current_slide).cycle('pause'); 
  $('#pause_button_'+i).hide();
  $('#play_button_'+i).show();
});
```

You must follow the naming convention above or any other you may decide on. the actual controls can be be place anywhere except inside the windows - bug issues.

On a side note, I set these pairs to pause immediately after they've been cycled because I didn't want several slide running on on page. I wanted the user to choose which one to cycle. Also, I have to find a way to turn off any other cycles that may be running.
However:

```
if(better_solution){
  return please_post;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll be doing any directory scraping - where are you going to get the rest of the information about each image from (title, caption, etc).  You'll need to put each section in a database, with reference to the image, which subsection should be opened when the user clicks the "learn more" button, section name, preview caption, etc.

I would suggest using a variant of the Galleria plugin: http://galleria.aino.se/

For the subpages (the destination for the "learn more" button), you can AJAX that into an absolute div that you pull to cover the entire slide show.  That makes the close button easy to implement - it just removes the absolute div all together.